# What's the best way to parse this kind of input?

Tags: java

I need to evaluate some strings (items titles) in order to decide if the item matches or not with some rules.

Regarding the rules, think about something like this.

```
((ball | balls) & messi) -ronaldo
```

The meaning is, if the title contains either `ball` or `balls` and `messi` (but `not ronaldo`) means that match.

What do you think is the best way to achieve this? (the rule must be written by end users and with a clear syntax, no regex)

Thanks!

Comment: your own logic implementation

Comment: I've used an XML rule engine for things like this in the past. Here's a starting point: http://www.jessrules.com/docs/71/xml.html

Comment: Since you say no regex, why did you include the regex tag?

Comment: @GeorgeJempty > He want to write an interpreter to turn "user friendly" syntax into regex or anything else that could filter strings, so most probably regex. If anyone ever manages to do that, it would definitley be a killer app, but that would probably already exist :-)

Comment: psabbate > a lot of developers I've talked to would just love such a tool given the complexity  of regex. But that's also what makes them so powerfull. I seriously doubt it's possible to write such a tool, but if you ever manage to do it, you could become a millionaire :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this library [Boolean Expressions](https://github.com/bpodgursky/jbool_expressions) and just built a wrapper to parse the keywords and works like a charm !!

Answer (score 0):

You may try something that uses plain English and yet follows the rules of logic.

For example -

```
(("ball" OR "balls") AND ("messi")) AND NOT ("ronaldo")
```

Essentially, you will need your own Logic Evaluator to parse this expression and evaluate it to true or false. You may also have another program that works on such rules supplied by the user and converts them to a format that is more friendly to your Logic Evaluator.